# Escaping the $ character in snippets

Tags: visual-studio, code-snippets

I find myself doing a ton of jQuery these days, so I started to abstract out some of the common things I do into snippets. I look forward to sharing these with the community, but I'm running into an issue right now.

The literals in snippets are defined by adding dollar signs ($) around the name of the literal to delimit where the value you would like to provide will go. This is difficult because jQuery uses the dollar sign notation in order to use a lot of its functionality.

What is the escape sequence for snippets, so I am able to use the dollar sign, and have my snippets still function?

Comment: More of a side note, but don't forget you can use `jQuery` instead of `$`

Comment: Note: This question is about _Visual Studio_, not _Visual Studio Code_; however, [this particular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43427442/45375) is about the latter.

Comment: use $$item instead of $item

Answer (score 184, accepted):

To have a literal `$` try doubling it: `$$`

Comment: @JosephMorgan It worked for me in C# (VS2015 for reference).

Comment: This approach still keep the cursor jumping to this position when tab is used. With this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43427442/1909798) I could escape correctly.

Comment: @robsonrosa it seems the answer you linked to emphasizes VSC (Visual Studio Code perhaps), so things may have changed between Visual Studio versions.

Comment: @AhmadMageed my bad. upvoting ;)

Comment: Worked for me also! VS2015

Comment: Works in VS2017, C#

Comment: Dear downvoters: this question and answer is old. It may not work in today's latest version. Rather than downvote, just upvote another answer that works with VSC or whatever version you're on.

Comment: Works for me in C#, VS2017.

Comment: Works in VS2019, C#

Comment: It works but it's not ideal, the next solution should be the approved one to escape "\\$"

Comment: Wow man searching for this for so long to escape this inside CDATA in XML and also for code snippet in Visual studio

Comment: Still works in VS 2022

Answer (score 129):

This is the right way for **Visual Studio *Code***: `\\$`.

This makes the `$` a literal part of the snippet rather than the start of a  [`$`-prefixed construct](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_snippet-syntax).

Comment: This doesn't mess up the tabbing in VSC. IE if you use the `$$` approach VSC assumes that you want to do something in those positions.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The currently accepted answer messes up when tabbing between $variables.

Comment: @hunt: This is the right answer for Visual Studio _Code_, whereas the question and the accepted answer are  about _Visual Studio_.

Comment: Still holds up in late 2021.

Comment: This answer is for Visual Studio Code, but the question is about Visual Studio.  (Thanks Microsoft for creating that confusion.)

Answer (score 26):

There is an "Delimiter" attribute defined for a Code element. This defaults to `$` but you can set it to a different character like `~` or so.

```
<Snippet>
<Code Language="JavaScript" Delimiter="~"><![CDATA[(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {

    });
})(jQuery);]]></Code>
</Snippet>
```

Comment: Not sure why this is not the accepted answer. `Delimiter` is _attribute that specifies the delimiter used to describe literals and objects in the code_ and its exact purpose is to replace the `$` if needed.`<Code Language="csharp" Delimiter="!"><![CDATA[Log.Debug(message: $"!end!");]]></Code>`

Answer (score 8):

Although the jQuery response is valid, it's a nicer syntax to use the $ notation.

I've found an answer: Making the $ character a literal with a default value of $.

```
<Literal Editable="true">

<ID>dollar</ID> <ToolTip>replace the dollar sign character</ToolTip> <Default>$</Default> <Function> </Function> </Literal>
```

Comment: I found that this works in C# for using the "$" for a Formattable string type.

Comment: I wasn't sure if adding an example was a comment or an answer, so because of length I added it below. It is based on this answer.

Answer (score 3):

I used this for a formattable string in C#. I used the example above from [cory-fowler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/333730/cory-fowler) verbatim:

```
<Literal Editable="true">
    <ID>dollar</ID>
    <ToolTip>Replace the dollar sign character</ToolTip>
    <Default>$</Default>
    <Function></Function>
</Literal>
```

Usage *(line breaks are added for clarity on Stack Overflow, not in the original.)*:

```
    string errMessage = $dollar$"Error occurred in
       {MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Module}, in procedure
       {MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name}: {ex.Message}".ToString();
```

Thanks, cory-fowler!

Answer (score 0):

I found the above [cory-fowler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/333730/cory-fowler) answer useful, but was frustrated that the literal $ was pre-selected when executing a C# snippet in VS 2019...

[image: Snippet with Literal Editable=true]

It was also ignoring my $end$ keyword...

`<![CDATA[string Literal_edit_true = $dollar$"$end$";]]>`

Simply changing to `Editable=false` resolved the issue and now the cursor appears at $end$ ready to type...

[image: Snippet with Literal Editable=false]

```
<Snippet>
    <Code Language="CSharp">
        <![CDATA[string Literal_edit_false = $dollar$"$end$";]]>
    </Code>
    <Declarations>
        <Literal Editable="false">
            <ID>dollar</ID>
            <ToolTip>Replace the dollar sign character</ToolTip>
            <Default>$</Default>
            <Function></Function>
        </Literal>
    </Declarations>
</Snippet>
```