# How to escape < character in visual studio snippet

Tags: visual-studio, code-snippets

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215705/snippets-question-escaping-the-character) question, I would like to know how to escape the "<" and ">" characters in a Visual Studio snippet literal element. I'm trying to make a Django url snippet, and the Django parameter names are enclosed in "<" and ">". Adding these characters gives an invalid syntax error in the xml file. Is there a way to escape these characters? Thanks!

Comment: Did you find an answer? I'm trying to invoke a generic method in C# with a snippet, but can't because of the `<` and `>`.

Comment: I did not. I went with a general parameter for the regex portion of the url, and am typing the < and > characters manually.

Comment: @DarrenHale, it's very late and so likely not an issue for you anymore, but I'm wondering if you ever found your answer, or if it's still relevant, if use of `&lt;` was/is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

My use case isn't python or django (it's SQL), and I'm not changing a 'literal' element (it's a 'code' element), but I don't think it matters.  The snippets are XML files.  So use `&lt;`.