# Escape $ in snippet

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I'm trying to escape the `$` character in my snippets but I cannot seem to get it correct.

If I use `\$` as it looks like I should be from the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/userdefinedsnippets#_grammar), I get the error:

```
file: path/to/snippets/php.json'
severity: 'Error'
message: 'Invalid escape character in string'
```

And no `$` appear in my snippet.

If I use `$$` found from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215705/snippets-question-escaping-the-character) answer, I get a `$` to show up but it thinks that the text immediately following is a tabstop.

If I use `$\` it works but I have to have a character that is part of an escape sequence immediately following. So if I wanted `$factory`, I would need to do `$\ffactory`. `\f` seems to be the best as it does not effect the layout of my snippet.

I'm pretty sure that I am missing what needs to be done here.

My snippet for reference:

```
"factory" :{
    "prefix": "factory",
    "body": [
        "\$factory->define($1, function (Faker\\Generator \$faker){",
        "\treturn [",
        "\t\t$2,",
        "\t];", 
        "}"
    ],
    "description": "Creates Model factory"
},
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After much trial and error, I found that using `\\$` will give me the desired results. So if I wanted `$test` in my snippet output, with `test` not being a tabstop, I would need `\\$test` snippet definition body:

```
"factory" :{
    "prefix": "factory",
    "body": [
        "\\$factory->define($1, function (Faker\\Generator \\$faker){",
        "\treturn [",
        "\t\t$2,",
        "\t];", 
        "});"
    ],
    "description": "Creates Model factory"
},
```