# Escaping $ dollar sign character in RStudio snippets

Tags: r, rstudio, code-snippets

I want to write a snippet that will allow me to put a string of text in multiple locations in my code, including after a `$`, to give the following expected result:

```
source("C:/R/Functions/[inserted_text].R")
.env$[inserted_text] <- [inserted_text]
```

I tried using the following snippet:

```
snippet srcfnc
    source('C:/Users/JT/R/Functions/${1:package}.R')
    .env$${1:package} <- ${1:package}
```

Unfortunately, this gives the result below:

```
source('C:/Users/JT/R/Functions/[inserted_text].R')
.env{1:package} <- [inserted_text]
```

I've looked [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205797578-Code-snippets-Write-a-literal-dollar-sign-) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215705/escaping-the-character-in-snippets/3215735), but none of the suggested solutions work in RStudio. I've also tried escaping the `$` with `\` as suggested [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/204463668-Code-Snippets?version=1.1.463&mode=desktop)

```
snippet test
    .env${1:package}
    .env$${1:package}
    .env$$${1:package}
    .env\$${1:package}
    .env\$$${1:package}
```

but I get these results:

```
.env[inserted_text]
.env{1:package}
.env[inserted_text]
.env\{1:package}
.env${1:package}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Answer from jemus42 on RStudio community site: "Does it have to be .env$something ? I thought the point of $ was to enable users to not have to write e.g. .env[[something]] (or with single brackets, depending). Point being: Can you get it to work with bracket notation instead of $?"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `${2:$}` to add a `"$"` sign.

For instance:

```
${1: mydata}${2:$}added_data
```

For your example this should work:

```
.env${2:$}${1:package} <- ${1:package}
```