Saving Shiny Code Snippet: Escaping $ Symbol Issues
I want to save this code as a snippet:
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textOutput("panel")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        id = "tabset",
        tabPanel("panel 1", "one"),
        tabPanel("panel 2", "two"),
        tabPanel("panel 3", "three")
      )
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$panel <- renderText({
    paste("Current panel: ", input$tabset)
  })
}

I do it in the usual way:
Tools -> Global Options -> Code -> Edit Snippets...
snippet my_shiny_tabsetPanel
    ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
    textOutput("panel")),
    mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
    id = "tabset",
    tabPanel("panel 1", "one"),
    tabPanel("panel 2", "two"),
    tabPanel("panel 3", "three")
    ))))
    server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$panel <- renderText({
    paste("Current panel: ", input$tabset)
    })
    }

and then save.
when I call the snippet I get:
ui <- fluidPage(
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
textOutput("panel")),
mainPanel(
tabsetPanel(
id = "tabset",
tabPanel("panel 1", "one"),
tabPanel("panel 2", "two"),
tabPanel("panel 3", "three")
))))
server <- function(input, output, session) {
output <- renderText({
paste("Current panel: ", input)
})
}


Please examine output$panel and input$tabset.
What is happening?
I have tried to escape $ using \$ or used $$. But without success.

perhaps just use output[["panel"]] <- renderText({paste("Current panel: ", input[["tabset"]])

This works. Thank you. Any idea about $?

i did not try this myself, but does it help you?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55368860/escaping-dollar-sign-character-in-rstudio-snippets

Any difference in saving snippet from terminal?

Never done this before, even don't know how to do!

The solution provided here should work. Basically, just use {2:$}
snippet my_shiny_tabsetPanel
    ui <- fluidPage(
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
                textOutput("panel")),
            mainPanel(
                tabsetPanel(
                    id = "tabset",
                    tabPanel("panel 1", "one"),
                    tabPanel("panel 2", "two"),
                    tabPanel("panel 3", "three")
                ))))
    server <- function(input, output, session) {
        output${2:$}panel <- renderText({
            paste("Current panel: ", input${2:$}tabset)
        })
    }

