# Visual Studio 2022 Snippets work incorrectly for C#

Tags: c#, code-snippets

I wrote a snippet , but c# snippet code writes half of the.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>MySql ExecuteNonQuery</Title>
            <Shortcut>psql_n</Shortcut>
            <Description>ExecuteNonQuery</Description>
            <Author>yhackup Corporation</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
                <SnippetType>SurroundsWith</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[
            try
            {
                using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * ct FROM arac_shadow WHERE heskod = @heskod ;", CreateConnection()))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@heskod", "");
                    if (command.Connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                        command.Connection.Open();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    command.Connection.Close();
                    command.Connection.ClearAllPoolsAsync();
                }
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"{MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name}.MySqlException : {ex.Message}");
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"{MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name}.SocketException : {ex.Message}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"{MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name} : {ex.Message}");
            }
            ]]></Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

[image]

but if i write the exception parts like this it's ok

```
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
    catch (SocketException ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
```

i couldn't understand what the problem was , If it was $ or { characters, it wouldn't be able to write the first line, I wonder what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Code snippets use `$...$` as placeholders, which explains why it's removed everything between the `$` in the `MySqlException` catch block, and the `$` in the `SocketException` catch block. Escape them (I assume with `\$`?)

Comment: throw new Exception(\  unfortunately that's what happened

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but why is this even a snippet? With this much code, you should be putting this into a shared method that you can call from other places.  If you need to change this snippet, you're going to have to change dozens or more code files too. Also, `throw new Exception(...)` is bad practice since you are hiding the stack trace.

Comment: The snippet code seems to eat up the ```$``` character from the string interpolation. Have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215705/escaping-the-character-in-snippets). You might need to double up the dollar signs in your snippet where needed.

Comment: Oh, and also you should not be using `AddWithValue`: https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/

Comment: @FlorinZamfir yes, as you said, changing $$ instead of $ fixed the problem thanks
yes, as you said, changing $$ instead of $ fixed the problem thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can specify another delimiter through the `Delimiter` attribute.

```
<Code Language="csharp" Delimiter="#">
```